# Why HttpClient blocks forever with chunked encoding?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

Here's a simple code snippet:

```
var httpMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://google.com"))
var task = client.SendAsync(httpMessage, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
var response = await task;
```

This code works just fine. When I replace it with my custom server which gives me chunked encoding "await task" hangs forever.

I've got backing code which is working through StreamSocket and I know that server works fine. I read http headers, parse incoming chunks e.t.c. The problem is why HttpClient hangs with chunked encoding?

UPDATE:

I forgot to mention that I'm using this CustomHttpHandler to allow untrusted certificates.

```
/// <summary>
///     An HttpMessageHandler that lets you use the Windows Runtime IHttpFilter types
/// </summary>
public class CustomHttpClientHandler : HttpMessageHandler
{
    static readonly List<ChainValidationResult> AllowedCertificateErrors =
        new List<ChainValidationResult>(){
            ChainValidationResult.Expired,
            ChainValidationResult.Untrusted,
            ChainValidationResult.InvalidName,
        };

    private static readonly Version NoVersion = new Version(0, 0);
    private static readonly Version Version10 = new Version(1, 0);
    private static readonly Version Version11 = new Version(1, 1);
    private static readonly Version Version20 = new Version(2, 0);
    private readonly rt.HttpClient _client;
    private bool _disposed = false;

    public CustomHttpClientHandler()
    {
        var filter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
        foreach (var error in AllowedCertificateErrors)
            filter.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(error);

        _client = new rt.HttpClient(filter);
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        CheckDisposed();

        var rtMessage = await ConvertHttpRequestMessageToRt(request, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        var resp = await _client.SendRequestAsync(rtMessage).AsTask(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        var netResp = await ConvertRtResponseMessageToNet(request, resp, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

        return netResp;
    }

    internal static async Task<rt.HttpRequestMessage> ConvertHttpRequestMessageToRt(HttpRequestMessage message, CancellationToken token)
    {
        var rt = new rt.HttpRequestMessage()
        {
            Method = new rt.HttpMethod(message.Method.Method),
            Content = await GetContentFromNet(message.Content).ConfigureAwait(false),
            RequestUri = message.RequestUri,
        };

        CopyHeaders(message.Headers, rt.Headers);

        foreach (var prop in message.Properties)
            rt.Properties.Add(prop);

        return rt;
    }

    internal static void CopyHeaders(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>>> source, IDictionary<string, string> destination)
    {
        var headers = from kvp in source
                      from val in kvp.Value
                      select new KeyValuePair<string, string>(kvp.Key, val);
        destination.Clear();
        foreach (var header in headers)
            destination.Add(header);
    }

    internal static async Task<rt.IHttpContent> GetContentFromNet(HttpContent content)
    {
        if (content == null)
            return null;

        rt.IHttpContent c;
        if (content is StringContent)
            c = new rt.HttpStringContent(await content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false), 
                Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8);
        else
        {
            var stream = await content.ReadAsStreamAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            c = new rt.HttpStreamContent(stream.AsInputStream());
        }

        CopyHeaders(content.Headers, c.Headers);

        return c;
    }

    internal static async Task<HttpContent> GetNetContentFromRt(rt.IHttpContent content, CancellationToken token)
    {
        if (content == null)
            return null;

        var str = await content.ReadAsInputStreamAsync().AsTask(token).ConfigureAwait(false);

        var c = new StreamContent(str.AsStreamForRead());

        foreach (var header in content.Headers)
            c.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation(header.Key, header.Value);

        return c;
    }

    internal static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ConvertRtResponseMessageToNet(HttpRequestMessage request, rt.HttpResponseMessage message, CancellationToken token)
    {
        var resp = new HttpResponseMessage((HttpStatusCode)(int)message.StatusCode)
        {
            ReasonPhrase = message.ReasonPhrase,
            RequestMessage = request,
            Content = await GetNetContentFromRt(message.Content, token).ConfigureAwait(false),
            Version = GetVersionFromEnum(message.Version),
        };

        foreach (var header in message.Headers)
            resp.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation(header.Key, header.Value);

        return resp;
    }

    internal static Version GetVersionFromEnum(rt.HttpVersion version)
    {
        switch (version)
        {
            case rt.HttpVersion.None:
                return NoVersion;
            case rt.HttpVersion.Http10:
                return Version10;
            case rt.HttpVersion.Http11:
                return Version11;
            case rt.HttpVersion.Http20:
                return Version20;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("version");
        }
    }

    private void CheckDisposed()
    {
        if (_disposed)
            throw new ObjectDisposedException("WinRtHttpClientHandler");
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && !_disposed)
        {
            _client.Dispose();

            _disposed = true;
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

On desktop I use HttpWebRequest to communicate with this server. But for WinRT I don't have an option to allow self-signed certificates with HttpWebRequest that's why i switched to HttpClient

Comment: `I know that server works fine` - are you sure? Maybe the content-length is e.g. one off?

Comment: It's a "hanging get" request which actually never ends. So I suppose it doesn't have Content-length. All other requests to this server are just fine since they're not chunked.

Comment: Try putting break points inside your custom handler, see if any of them get hit and cause the deadlock.

Comment: Exactly this line causes deadlock:  var resp = await _client.SendRequestAsync(rtMessage).AsTask(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

Comment: Try doing the following: `await Task.Run(async () => await _client.SendRequestAsync(rtMessage).AsTask(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(fal‌​se));`. I want to see if it changes anything.

Comment: Can you get Fiddler logs?